# value is not setting as expected

Tags: javascript

```js
var x;//in case the function pointing to global x instead of function x
let func = () => {
    var x;
    let get=()=>console.log("value of x = ",x);
    let set=(val)=>{x=val;console.log("value of x setted = ",x);}
    return {get,set}
}

func().set(10);//returns value of x = 10
func().get();//returns value of x setted = undefined
```

Here I'm setting a value of `x` to some value and I'm trying to get a value of `x` after setting,the get method is returning undefined. It should have `10` as I expected... help me out. The scope issue may be the reason I think... Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time when you call `func`, you create two different objects. When you set the value via the first `call`, it creates a new object and sets the value for the first object, which is lost, because you don't keep the reference. And for the second call it creates a new object again and because you don't set the value for the second one, you get `undefined`.

```js
let func = () => {
   var x;
   let get=()=>console.log("value of x = ",x);
   let set=(val)=>{x=val;console.log("value of x setted = ",x);}
   return {get,set}
}

const obj = func();

obj.set(10);
obj.get();
```

**After update**

Your local `x` variable shadows the global one. Accessing `x` in the function always get the `function scoped` variable `x` - `var x`.

```js
let x;
let func = () => {
   let get=()=>console.log("value of x = ",x);
   let set=(val)=>{x=val;console.log("value of x setted = ",x);}
   return {get,set}
}

func().set(10);
func().get();
```

Answer (score 1):

create a local variable and call the functions

```js
let func = () => {
var x;
let set=(val)=>{x=val;console.log("value of x setted = ",x);}
let get=()=>console.log("value of x = ",x);
return {get,set}
}
var f=func();
f.set(10);
f.get();
//    func().set(10);//returns value of x = 10
//   func().get();//returns value of x setted = undefined
```